# Extracting IP from request in Python

Tags: python, http, header, request, ip

I have a Pythonic HTTP server that is supposed to determine client's IP. How do I do that in Python? Is there any way to get the request headers and extract it from there?

PS: I'm using WebPy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use web.ctx:

```
class example:
    def GET(self):
        print web.ctx.ip
```

More info [here](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ctx)

Answer (score 3):

web.env.get('REMOTE_ADDR')